# Can JustMock return a value based on the parameter?

Tags: mocking, telerik, justmock

Using JustMock, can I arrange a mock to return something based on the input parameter?

For example, say a method takes in an `int`, I want to return that value + 1
I want the output to always be mocked as input+1 but I don't know the input at design time.

My real usage for this is with an object parameter and I need to mock to always return a new object having *some* of the same properties... but I do not know how to reference the parameters in the `.Returns()` section.

**EDIT:** More details:

Three types:
`IMoneyConverter`
`Money`
`Currency`

A `Money` object has two properties: `decimal valueAmount` and `Currency valueCurrency`

`IMoneyConverter` exposes:

```
.Convert(Money valueFrom, Currency currencyTo, DateTime asOfDate)
```

This method returns the converted `Money` object, in the new `Currency` (currencyTo) as of the specified date.

My intent is to mock the `IMoneyConverter` so that its `.Convert` method returns a new `Money` object having the amount of the `Money` (valueFrom) parameter and the `Currency` of the  currencyTo parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understood the exact requirements, but this test works and I believe will demonstrate how to accomplish what you want:

```cs
[Test]
public void SampleTest() {
   IMoneyConverter mock = Mock.Create<IMoneyConverter>();
   mock.Arrange( x => x.Convert( Arg.IsAny<Money>(), Arg.IsAny<Currency>(), Arg.IsAny<DateTime>() ) )
      .Returns( (Func<Money,Currency,DateTime,Money>)
         ( (m, c, d ) => new Money { ValueAmount = m.ValueAmount, Currency = c }) );

   Money inMoney = new Money() { ValueAmount = 42 };
   Currency inCurrency = new Currency();
   Money outMoney = mock.Convert( inMoney, inCurrency, DateTime.Now );
   Assert.AreEqual( 42, outMoney.ValueAmount  );
   Assert.AreSame( inCurrency, outMoney.Currency );
}

public interface IMoneyConverter {
   Money Convert( Money valueFrom, Currency currencyTo, DateTime asOfDate );
}

public class Money {
   public decimal ValueAmount { get; set; }
   public Currency Currency { get; set; }
}

public class Currency {
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's possible, see example.

```cs
var foo = Mock.Create<IFoo>();
Mock.Arrange(() => foo.Echo(Arg.IsAny<int>())).Returns((int i) => ++i);
```

Comment: Where does the `int i` come from?

Comment: @MatthewPK You can read about lambda expressions on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)